# The antonym for 'Hacking'

Tags: antonyms

While working in IT, it is common to refer to a quick and dirty solution to a problem as a 'Hack'.

For example, if your chair legs are uneven, a hack for this problem would be to place a piece of paper underneath one of the legs such that it compensates for the difference in length to the ground.

On the opposite end of the spectrum, it is also possible to Overengineer a solution and create a chair that universally accommodates uneven floors.

Would there be an elegant one syllable word that describes the latter undertaking?

I had a look around online on other websites and 'Splicing' was suggested, as it refers to the joining of strings rather than 'Hacking' them apart (Messily).
Personally I think this term has already been used too much in genetics and icecreams and was hoping for an alternative.

Thanks!

Edit: An example of usage for such a word would probably be:
- in the context of a Hackathon of some kind, one would say "This isn't a hack, it is *****" or if someone degrades your work you'd say "I'm not hacking, I'm *****ing"

or something along those lines.

Comment: Elegant solutions rarely have elegant one-word descriptions.

Comment: That seems contrary to the concept though doesnt it?

Comment: Unclear:  Are you trying to describe the 3-leg stool or the 7-leg chair with automatic servo adjusters?

Comment: @HotLicks Hacking describes the 3 leg stool.

Comment: No, the 3-leg stool is elegant, because it's inherently stable.

Comment: @HotLicks Ahh I see what you mean (I hadn't considered that!) yes then the 3 legged chair solution is exactly what I'm talking about!

Comment: @ermanen Inventing could be the word, but the activity doesn't seem to be the opposite of hacking.

Comment: (The 7-leg chair with automatic servo adjusters is a kluge, BTW.)

Comment: @Liang: Actually, you are not asking the opposite of hacking exactly. For example, if hacking is a temporary solution as a quick fix, inventing is a permanent and universal solution.

Comment: @Liang: The activity can be "creating" or even "engineering".

Comment: @ermanen engineering seems like the obvious choice, :). I was hoping there was something more fanciful and playful out there, but I guess there might not be. Thanks!

Comment: perhaps ***crafting***

Comment: I can certainly see "I'm not hacking, I'm engineering" and "This isn't a hack, it's an invention" as things people might say defensively.  However, I'm not sure that the person on the listening end of the conversation would always agree!  *Overengineering*, which you used in the question, certainly describes the 7-legged chair with automatic adjusters.  But *well-crafted*, to modify @Jim's suggestion, might be the right word for a well-built 3-leg stool.

Comment: Also, [this is relevant](http://xkcd.com/974/).  *Perfectionist* / *Master artisan* would be good descriptions for the person who implements the anti-Hack.

Answer (score 4):

*Hack*

*Hack* is a contranym. Hence, "it's a really dirty hack, but it'll do the job for now" and "Alice had a stroke of genius and came up with a beautiful hack that solved it neatly".

Comment: +1 IT definition of 'hack' is to make something better, and the antonym therefore is 'crack', but don't think that's what the OP is looking for?

Comment: @Christopher well, both of those senses of *hack* mean to make it better (even a dirty hack makes things better if the starting state is it doesn't work and the resulting state is it mostly works) but differ as to how well they do so, so its a contranym only in regards to those elements. I'm not sure I'd consider *crack* as an antonym since it's specific to deliberate harm and the same thing could be both a hack and a crack if it was a clever piece of work (*hack*) that was used maliciously (*crack*) though most cases of one are not cases of the other.

Answer (score 3):

If *hacking* refers to a quick and personalized solution (similar to *jury-rigging*), ***engineering*** refers to a well-researched and universal solution.

> *engineer:* to originate, cause, or plan in a clever or devious manner [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/engineer)

Other possible terms are ***inventing***, creating something new; and ***innovating***,  making changes on something established by introducing new ideas or products.

Comment: Bonus: http://www.slideshare.net/the_undefined/building-an-alarm-clock-with-nodejs

Answer (score 2):

The opposite of a quick and dirty method that works (in terms of the best possible solution) would be:

> ***Best practice***...a method or technique that has consistently shown results superior to those achieved with other means, and that is used as a benchmark. - [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_practice)

An alternate noun phrase antonym that many would regard as suitably applicable would be:

> ***Gold standard***: ...2 A model of excellence; a paragon: "Several generations of the laser have been widely available in Europe; the FDA approved the one now considered the gold standard" (Daniel Goleman). - *American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company.*
>
> ...2. the supreme example of something against which others are judged or measured: the current gold standard for breast cancer detection. - *Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003*
>
> source - [freedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gold+standard)

Answer (score 0):

**Mashup** ?

Strictly speaking the definition of mash (to join things together) is a good opposite for "hack" (to take things apart). And in the world of computers it also has a niche use somewhat like the word "hack" does. See the Wikipedia article for [mashup (web application hybrid)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mashup_(web_application_hybrid)).

It also seems to be a good synonym for "splice"

> a mixture or fusion of disparate elements.

Maybe it's usage is a bit too specific. I'm not positive this fits the bill as asked, but I thought I'd put it out there.